# java: default number-formatting

Tags: java

I have a program that does algorithmic calculations with some number-output. I want this output to look nice and the program still being fast. I used the DecumalFormat but this makes it so slow, but works.
Is there a way to set the default number output so I wouldnt need DecimalFormat???

```
Locale deLocale = new Locale("de_DE");
// should be format:  ###,###.###    123.456,789     de_DE

Locale.setDefault (deLocale);

double f=-123456.123458998;
System.out.println (""+f+"");  // I wourld expect -123.456,123
// but the output is -123456.123458998
```

any ideas?? thanks!
chris

Comment: Do you really output that many numbers that formatting them is the thing slowing you down? Who can ever hope to actually **read** those numbers? Or in other words: I'm **sure** that you can format numbers **a lot** faster than any human can read them.

Comment: If the speed of output formatting is _really_ a concern, you could consider splitting the production of your raw data output and your nicely formatted output into different threads or processes. Blast out your raw data and format it later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [Customizing Format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

You need a `###,###.###  - de_DE` pattern.

```
String pattern= "###,###.###";
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
double f=-123456.123458998;
String output = myFormatter.format(f);
System.out.println(f+ " " + pattern + " " + output);
```

---

**EDIT :** Use [Predefined format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html), in case you don't want your own pattern.

Comment: as far I see this site only shows how to set the format by every output. thats to slow for me. I want to set it generelly.

Comment: sorry, but in all this examples i see the call of format (which is too expensive for me).
I am looking for a way to tell java generally to format numbers.